# How to make numbers of nocite citations appear

Tags: biblatex, citing

I want to make a biblatex item appear in the bibliography without having cited it explicitly. This can be done with \nocite{*}, but in the bibliography, only the items that have been cited with \cite appear to have a number. A MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=numeric,
sorting=nyt]
{biblatex}
\addbibresource{smth.bib}

\begin{document}
According to \cite{first item}...
\nocite{second item}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I would get:

[1] First item 
Second item

Instead of

[1] First item 
[2] Second item

EDIT: It seems like the issue comes from a figure and a center environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=numeric,
sorting=nyt]
{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{example.bib}
  @misc{guion,
author= "{Laboratorio de Física.}",
title="Determinación de índices de refracción",
year="2023",
howpublished=" Disponible en \url{https://fisicas.ucm.es/file/prac22-2223-v0?ver}",
}

@misc{sears,
    author    = "{Sears y Zemansky}",
    title     = "Física Universitaria con Física Moderna",
    publisher = "Pearson",
    volume   = "2",
    edition  = "13",
    year      = "2013",
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{example.bib}
\begin{document}
According to \cite{guion}...
\nocite{*}

\section{Lorem ipsum}
%\centering


%---------------------Figure with \centering inside -------------%
%\begin{figure}[h]
%\centering
%\includegraphics[]{dummy.png}
%\end{figure}

\begin{center} % Should be equivalent to centering
\printbibliography[title=Bibliography]
\end{center}
 
%\includegraphics[]{dummy.png}

%\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Toggling `\centering` instead of a `center` environment makes it work, but not the other way round.

I don't get how introducing a figure with \centering before the bibliography can affect it in any way. Isn't it supposed to be a condition that only holds inside the float?

Comment: The number of `\nocite`d entries should appear in the bibliography. If I turn the code snippet into code I can compile (I don't have `smth.bib`): https://gist.github.com/moewew/c292ce00ef26a471e5288676a7373f92 I obtain https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8TDB.png with a number also for the `\nocite`d entry. Please change your MWE so that we can compile it and post a screenshot of the MWE, not your larger document.

Comment: How should I change the MWE? I'm new here so I don't know what's wrong. 'smth.bib' is just a dummy name.

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and  https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864. It's important that your code is compilable as-is and that you compiled it and verified it reproduces the issue.

Comment: It seems like the \center environment was causing problems. Yet I have another project with exactly the same lines of code (that is, \begin{center}, \printbibliography, and end{center}) but it does work. ????

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `\begin{center}...\end{center}` to centre section headings. The environment creates a list (and grouping), which may interfere with other typesetting. In this case it messes with the bibliography, which is also typeset as a list, leading to a nested list.

The following reproduces the issue more compactly

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
Lorem\cite{sigfridsson,worman}

\section{Ipsum}

\begin{center}
\printbibliography
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The best solution here depends  be on your requirements. Presumably you used `\begin{center}...\end{center}` to typeset the bibliography heading centred. Do you want to centre all section headings, all unnnumbered section headings or only the bibliography heading?

If you only want to change the bibliography heading, one fairly clean solution is to insert a `\centering` into the `\section*` call.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\defbibheading{bibliography}[\refname]{%
  \section*{\centering#1}%
  \@mkboth{\abx@MakeMarkcase{#1}}{\abx@MakeMarkcase{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Lorem\cite{sigfridsson,worman}

\section{Ipsum}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: References with numbering]

Comment: I only wanted to change bibliography heading, yes. However, I don't have any idea as to what you are doing between makeatletter and makeatother.

Comment: @JaimeYepesdePaz I took [the original definition of `\defbibheading{bibliography}` for `article`-like classes](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/24a94f8f608872e11d259d7c581fc90ea76542a5/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L1893-L1895) and added a `\centering` to the `\section*` call.